# Spring Boot Injection issue using several Profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm having an issue using Profiles in Spring, basically, we use them to stub some parts of our microservice, which uses both a connection to DB and a connection to another webservice.

Previously I used one stub profile for both the DB and external webservice :

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @Profile("stub")
    @ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.consumption.backend"},
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.consumption.backend.*.persistence.*"),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.consumption.backend.databackendapi.*")
    })
    public class StubConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public DataApi consumptionApi() { return new DataStubApi(); }

        @Bean
        public RefDayDao refDayDao() { return new RefDayInMemoryDao(); }

        @Bean
        public RefTypeHourDao refTypeHourDao() { return new RefTypeHourInMemoryDao(); }

    }
```

and this works fine, however I would like to separate this stub into two stubs, one for the DB and one for the external webservices to ensure greater flexibility in our tests.

Stub for the DAO:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @Profile("stubconfv3")
    @ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.consumption.backend"},
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.consumption.backend.*.persistence.*")
    )
    public class StubConfV3Configuration {

        @Bean
        public RefDayDao refDayDao() { return new RefDayInMemoryDao(); }

        @Bean
        public RefTypeHourDao refTypeHourDao() { return new RefTypeHourInMemoryDao(); }

    }
```

Stub for the external webservice :

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @Profile("stubdatabackend")
    @ComponentScan(
            basePackages = {"com.consumption.backend"},
            excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern =         "com.consumption.backend.databackendapi.*")
    )
    public class StubDataBackendConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public DataApi consumptionApi() { return new DataStubApi(); }

    }
```

The stub for the DAO seems to work fine, however I seem to have an issue with the external webservice API not excluding the implementation properly:

- If I launch my application with `stub` profile everything works fine
- If I launch my application with `stubconfv3` and `stubdatabackend` I get an issue with injection, as two classes are found :

> Parameter 0 of constructor in
> com.consumption.backend.service.DataService required a single bean,
> but 2 were found:
>
> - dataBackendApi: defined in file [C:\code\consumption-backend\databackend-api\target\classes\com\consumption\backend\databackendapi\DataBackendApi.class]
> - consumptionApi: defined by method 'consumptionApi' in class path resource
>   [com/consumption/backend/application/configuration/StubDataBackendConfiguration.class]
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the
> consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the
> bean that should be consumed

Either the exclusion is not working or there is some tricky thing as it seems to find the .class file in target instead of finding it at runtime in a class loader

Most likely, I do some stupid mistake and am not seeing it ...

EDIT : I noticed if I misstype `stubconfv3` profile in `StubConfV3Configuration`, the injection issue doesn't appear anymore, so I guess you can't combine exclusionFilters in `@ComponentScan` in two different classes...
The first class will do a componentscan on everything but what she excludes, and the second will do the same, so packages excluded by the second class with still be scanned by the first class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to annotate your DataBackendApi with

```
@Profile("!stubdatabackend")
```

to include it when that profile is not used and exclude it otherwise

Comment: That's a good idea and it works, however shouldn't the filter   
`excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern =         "com.consumption.backend.databackendapi.*")` in `@ComponentScan` of `StubDataBackendConfiguration ` take care of that ?  
And I checked and double checked and this package path in the regex is the right one  
  
And why does this exclusion filter works with the all-in-one stub but not with the two separated stubs ?

Comment: accepting your answer as I didn't find a better solution